# How can I type a backslash (\) in Tera Term instead of a yen symbol (¥)?

Tags: terminal-emulator

When using the Tera Term terminal emulator, a yen symbol (¥) appears every time I try entering a backslash (\). This happens even if I try pasting a backslash in or using keyboard shortcuts.

How can I enter a backslash in Tera Term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the language to English and change the font to Courier in order to be able to enter the backslash character in Tera Term. You can either do so manually every time using the UI or change the config file.

To do this in the UI, first go to Setup > General... and set Language to English. Then, go to Setup > Font > Font... and set Font to Courier.

To do this in the config file, first open the file called TERATERM.ini. Then, set Language=English and VTFont=Courier,0,-19,128.